# Write in syslog using templates and dynamic data

Tags: database, templates, dynamic, random, syslog

I am looking for a utility that can help me writing random logs in syslog.

I have three requirements :

- Need to define template for different types of logs messages.
- Need to generate random dynamic logs using that templates
- Need to store the dynamic values generated in some data base (JSON format preferably) which I can access later easily.

> ```
> For example define a template like
>
> mytemplate = (my name is %name. My email address is %email)
>
> Then dynamically generate logs like this
>
> my name is John. My email address is john123@domain.com
> my name is marry. My email address is marry22@domain.com
>
> Also store these dynamic records in some data base.
> ```

I have looked at various utilities likes **syslog-ng, rsyslogd** seems like they are fulfilling my puropse but still need experts opinion on that that which utility is suitable for me.

Also I am unable to find any example of language. Like which language do I need to use to fulfill this requirement.

Any help will be appreciated.